# Does Spring's JDBCTemplate properly closes connections when manually instantiated?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1 RC1 and i have this method that generates a `JDBCTemplate` object based on properties defined in a database:

```
public JdbcTemplate generateDatasource(Environment env){

        String url = String.format("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//%s:%s/%s",env.getIp(), env.getPort(), env.getSid());

        return new JdbcTemplate(
                DataSourceBuilder.create()
                        .url(url)
                        .username(env.getUser())
                        .password(env.getPassword())
                        .driverClassName(driver)
                        .build()
        );

    }
```

I notice it logs "Hikari Pool started" everytime this method is called and this makes me worry about memory leaks. The variable that holds the returned object is a local variable so i know the Garbage Collector gets rid of it. Can i be sure JDBC connections will be closed after executing some queries?

Comment: Shouldn't dataSources be reused? You are starting a pool on each method invocation. The one who subsequentially invokes DataSource#getConnection is responsible for closing that connection.

Comment: _everytime this method is called_ The returned `JdbcTemplate` should be a Spring bean and injected wherever needed.  It's thread safe so the method should only be called once.  But to answer your direct question, yes the Connection (and Statement and ResultSet) are closed (check the source code).